# My Python code doesn't satisfy all test cases although my logic is correct

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm trying to write a Python code to solve a problem: Complete the gameOfThrones function below to determine whether a given string can be rearranged into a palindrome. If it is possible, return YES, otherwise return NO.

My logic is that if the input string has an even length, then all the number of characters in the string must be even. However, if the string has an odd length, all the characters must have even number of characters except for one character that has odd number.

The code that I have written is below:

```
 def gameOfThrones(s):

    d = {}

    s = sorted(s)
    count = 0
    for i in s:
        if i not in d:
            d[i] = 1
        else:
            d[i] += 1

    if len(s) % 2 == 0:
        for v in d.values():
            if v % 2 != 0:
                print("NO")
            else:
                print("YES")
    else:
        for v in d.values():
            if v % 2 == 1:
                count += 1
        if count > 1:
            print("NO")
        elif count == 1:
            print("YES")
```

I'm not sure where I went wrong. The code seems to make sense to me. Please assist, thank you in advance.

Comment: So which test cases fail, and what is your output for those? Please also fix the indentation of your code.

Comment: You need to convert the sting to `lower` or `upper` case, if it is failing because of using different `case` in input string

Comment: I suggest a first debugging step would be to run code on different inputs and see what it outputs and if that aligns with what you think it should output. "The code seems to make sense to me" suggests you have only looked at it, not run it.

Comment: You should write down your logic in words. Then compare your code to determine if what the code does matches what the words say.

Comment: By the way, why do you think you need to sort the string? And if you do sort the string, then there's no need for `d`, because like characters will be together and you can count and check for odd/even with a single pass over the sorted string.

Answer (score 0):

I try to run your code with 2 tests as follows:

```
def gameOfThrones(s):
    d = {}
    s = sorted(s)
    count = 0
    for i in s:
        if i not in d:
            d[i] = 1
        else:
            d[i] += 1

    if len(s) % 2 == 0:
        for v in d.values():
            if v % 2 != 0:
                print("NO")
            else:
                print("YES")
    else:
        for v in d.values():
            if v % 2 == 1:
                count += 1
        if count > 1:
            print("NO")
        elif count == 1:
            print("YES")


gameOfThrones("aabb")
gameOfThrones("aabbbccc")

# output
YES
YES
NO
NO
YES
```

As you can see, your code outputs 5 answers for 2 tests.

2 issues in code: not breaking after finding an odd-number character for even-length s, and printing too many "YES" whenever finding an even-number character in an even-length s

```
if len(s) % 2 == 0:
    for v in d.values():
        if v % 2 != 0:
            print("NO")  // break
        else:
            print("YES")  // incorrect logic
```